# missing New Case Button, in groups

Tags: lightning, button, public-group

I cannot put the button to create a New case, on a public group layout. Just like here:

[image]

from this trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_implementation_chatter/lex_implementation_chatter_groups?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-administrator-credential

I know i've got in the layout, as in:
[image]

also:

1. have it in the lightning Layout, and registered for all profiles and Apps:
   [image]
2. The Allow Records in Groups check, in Chatter setting is on. Buttons Create Contacts, Account, Community Cases (but not Cases), and Campaigns work well.

[image]

But it just wont show on the group.
3. I have an admin Profile, in a developer org, and im the owner of this public group.

4. In classic, none of those show: only File, Link, Poll, Question and Announcement

[image]

What am i missing? How can i add the New Case Button?

Thanks All!

Edit: Just tried in a new Custom public group, and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to the Record Types settings for the action.

Please search for "Global actions" in the quick find box of Salesforce settings. There you will see a list of actions, and one will be the "New Case".

If you click edit, it will probably be pointing to the Master layout. As you may be using Record Types for the layouts, you will need to point to one you created, to be able to see the button.

Hope this helps.